# Cucumber tests do not run in specified order, what is wrong?

Tags: android, kotlin, automated-tests, cucumber

So here is my problem: I have a set of tests, which I want to run in a specific order. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781629/how-to-order-feature-files-in-cucumber-test-suite) question I found out that you could simply write down the sequence of the tests as you'd like them to run.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to run on my Kotlin implementation, for reasons I cannot see.

This is what I have:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = ["features/test1.feature", "features/test2.feature", "features/test3.feature", "features/test4.feature", "features/test5.feature"])
```

Additional info: all tests are in the same directory, all test names are specific - I have renamed them here for readability.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to run the tests in a specific order?

Comment: Since most of the tests require a logged in user, I wanted to simply make one "Login" test, then the tests with the requirements and then a "Logout" test to encapsulate the pack.

Comment: This is a bad practice. All tests should be independent and isolated from each other. You can use Before and After hooks to perform the login and logout on each scenario or you can simulate global hooks using this example:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/515

Comment: You could define the order of execution if all scenarios are in the same feature. But the reason you want to do it doesn't justify this approach. If you have more than 1 scenario in the same feature and all of them require login info the system, you could just put a step "Given I have logged into the system with user ..." in the part Background of the feature and this step will be executed before each scenario. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that it once executed in order is just an implementation detail you happened to notice - there is no guarantee on execution order of scenarios. In fact it is bad practice to depend on execution order for a scenario - I speak from experience here and highly recommend you change the way you are doing this.

The solution we eventually came up with was requiring a step in the background such as "Given I login as USER/PASSWORD".  If logging in is extremely expensive you might consider using Cucumber hooks @Before and caching the login in some sort of `World` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the feature files and cucumber will start running them in the order you want

Like for example:

```
01Featurefile.feature
02Featurefile.feature
03Featurefile.feature
```

This will make cucumber run 01 and 02 and then 03 in order.

Please note this is the last resort which can be implemented in order to run in order to cope up with test case dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For common unit-tests you can use annotation `@org.junit.FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)`. In that case methods will be started by alphabet.