# Run multiple feature files of Cucumber through command line with using CucumberOptions but without using Tag

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

We have a requirement to run dependent feature files together through Command line in sequential manner.

Example:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/featureFiles/UserManager/UserManager.feature" -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/featureFiles/WebSiteOperation/WebsiteOperationIPC.feature"
```

I want to make sure first `UserManager.feature` file executing and then its dependent `WebsiteOperationIPC.feature` file should be run.

Currently while running command as mentioned above, its not working as expected and skipping `UserManager.feature` file and executing second feature file first.

Comment: Can you please see this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781629/how-to-order-feature-files-in-cucumber-test-suite

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I've gone through it.
But here requirement is bit different. Do you have any reference to run the dependent feature files through command line?